# undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager

Tags: authentication

Hi I'm trying to protect my profile edition webpage with

```
auth()->$user->profile->update($data);
```

but i'm getting this error,

> undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::${"id":1,"name":"mourad","surname":"BENOSB","email":"mourad.benosmane@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2020-01-04 11:41:28","updated_at":"2020-01-04 11:41:28"}
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
$data = $request->all();

auth()->user()->profile->update($data);

// $data should be an array; update() function accepts is only
//array and those key should be on fillable under its model
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.